# Get trimester (quarter) code in c#

Tags: c#, windows, datetime

i needed to get the correspondent trimester (periods of 3 months, being the first trimester Jan, Feb and Mar) of a given date. Using the c# System.DateTime struct I didn't manage to find a method for what I was looking for. So I solved like this:

```
DateTime sDeathDate = DateTime.Parse("18/09/1970");
int iDeathTrimester = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(sDeathDate.Month) / 3 + 0.25));
```

If someone knows a easier way to do this, please answer.

André

Comment: How would you define a trimester?

Comment: From wiki: An academic term comprising one-third of an academic year or The division of pregnancy into three-month sections. Definition only fits code if women get pregnant in january :-)

Comment: BTW, three months calls quarters, not trimester.

Comment: Trimester comes from latin, meaning three months

Comment: Where I come from (The Netherlands) a trimester equals 1/3 of a school year, and since we spread our school holidays based on the region the school is in, a trimester has a different start and end date each year with the first trimester starting after the summer holiday. So, calculating the trimester from the date could be very complex depending on what definition of a trimester you use.

Comment: hmm true, ambiguous word. Anyway, Trimester -> periods of 3 months. I'd say pregnancy changing to sPregnancyDate :-)

Comment: As the OP refers to sDeathDate.Month, it seems unlikely that he is talking about school

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming Jan - Mar is trimester 1, Apr - Jun is trimester 2, Jul - Sep is Trimester 3 and Oct - Dec is trimester 4, then you can use

```
int trimester = (sDeathDate.Month - 1) / 3 + 1
```

This is the same as a quarter, did you mean something different?

Comment: That's it. I edited the question explaining what I meant by trimester. Let's say the woman got pregnant in January :-) 
Thank you all.

Comment: That's an option, but this solution does not use a round method, which is proved it does not fail.

Comment: @Amadio, are you saying that using round method has advantages comparing to this one above.

Comment: There's no need to do any rounding, as this solution is using integer division

Comment: I'm from the opinion that is better to use the framework better than to reinvent the world, also using the framework you have the method that does it and is sure is not gonna fail. Also I say this way of solving it, is nice, but for complex calculation is best to have it sure it will go right than have to test later.

Comment: I believe integer division is part of "the framework", also this doesn't quite qualify as a "complex calculation".

Answer (score 5):

[Math.Ceiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ceiling%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) Returns the smallest integer greater than or equal to the specified number.

```
DateTime sDeathDate = DateTime.Parse("18/11/1970");
int trimester = (int)Math.Ceiling(sDeathDate.Month/3.0);
```

Note that the code use ***3.0*** to perform a floating point division and not an integer division

Answer (score 1):

The [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx) includes the class *Quarter* (period of 3 months):

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void QuarterOfDateSample()
{
  DateTime moment = new DateTime( 1970, 9, 15 );
  Console.WriteLine( "Quarter  : {0}", new Quarter( moment ) );
  // > Quarter  : Q3 1970; 01.07.1970- 30.09.1970| 91.23:59

  Console.WriteLine( "Quarter  : {0}", new Quarter( 2006, YearQuarter.First ) );
  // > Quarter  : Q1 2006; 01.01.2006 - 31.03.2006 | 89.23:59
} // QuarterOfDateSample
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Math.Round (Double, MidpointRounding)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ef48waz8%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) you can do the round better without adding `0,25`

See you